# Apt error during Ubuntu Server (Hardy) install

Tags: ubuntu, installation, apt

I'm installing Ubuntu server 8.04 (hardy) on a machine. Te installation process goes well until the part of package installation.

The machine is behind a proxy. I configure the proxy correctly and the process fails. It said it was a problem trying to configure the package manager.

Checking the syslog in /var/log (Using Alt+F2) I found the following message:

```
E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf:2: Extra junk at end of file
```

I faced this problem in a regular machine before. Probably is missing the ';' on the end of the proxy string in apt.conf file.

I tried putting the ';' when the system asks me for proxy, but that didn't work.

I had the same problem trying Ubuntu Server 10.04 (Lucid)

I don't have access to /etc/apt/apt.conf (Probably is on the CDROM)

I don't want to finish process and continue because I'll have to install everything on my own, and this is a modified CD (the hardy, not the lucid).

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those looking for the solution:

You can edit the file in `/target/etc/apt/apt.conf`